# Arduino Bluetooth mouse MOUSE_LEFT work as MOUSE_RIGHT on Samsung Note 10

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I have the following arduino code which should press a left mouse button over Bluetooth.

```
#include <BleMouse.h>
BleMouse bleMouse("Mouse");

...

void loop() {
  ...
  bleMouse.press(MOUSE_LEFT);
  ...
}
```

On android in Samsung A70 and in windows 10 work as left button. But on the Samsung Note 10 it works as `MOUSE_RIGHT`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard Bluetooth HID protocol. If it works with other devices / operating systems I'd presume that either Samsung Note 10, at least with your current OS is does not comply with that standard. Or that there is some left/right hand configuration. The latter seems more likely to me.

So either fix whatever is wrong on your device or alter the android BlePeripheral library.